# Feed java with characters/string/bytestream from a c# class

Tags: c#, java, oledb

I want to have a java app running, using a function/method (with as little delay as possible I hope!) in a c# class...
The c# function takes a string from the java app, and returns a string.. Had to do it in c# to make a OleDbConnection in windows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you need.

If you need to call Java code from inside C#, you could try [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/).

If you need to launch a standalone Java app, use whatever .NET has for spawning subprocesses.

If the only reason why you're using C# is OleDbConnection, you could see if there's a Java driver for the database you need to contact. Or an ODBC driver, and use the JDBC/ODBC bridge.

Answer (score 0):

I am author of [jni4net](http://jni4net.sf.net/), open source interprocess bridge between JVM and CLR. It's build on top of JNI and PInvoke. No C/C++ code needed. I hope it will help you.